# Is there a MSMQ function similar to IBMs PUT1

Tags: msmq, mq

As the title suggests.

Ive been doing research on MSMQ as much as i can and i wanted to know does MSMQ have a similar function like IBM's MTPUT1.

Meaning is there a way i can just put a message on a destination queue without connecting and opening that queue.

MQPUT1 does this by setting the QMName and QName.

Is there something similar in MSMQ ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, not in the standard API anyway (which is the one I use).

Since MSMQ has `MQSendMessage`, the equivalent function would be something like `MQSendMessageOne` (seeing Microsoft's propensity for loquaciousness), which does not exist.

I've always thought IBM was bat-crazy here, they should have either ditched that call altogether, or provided an equivalent `MQGET1` as well, then at least there would have been balance and harmony in the universe. Though it galls me to say it, this is one Microsoft got right :-)

In any case, writing `MQSendMessageOne` in terms of the open/send/close functions should be a fairly trivial task.